# Bcrypt / Blowfish invalid salt with low number of rounds < 04

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt, blowfish

It seems that the hashpw function does not allow a hash that have a number of rounds < 04.

It appears to be the case with every bcrypt version >= 3.1.1

As a transition to python 3, the new library does not allow such hash with '${version}$01${value}', it needs to be at least 04.

I understand the security reasons but is there a way to force a minimum number of rounds to be accepted?

The error seems to be thrown by blowfish, used in bcrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change it unless rebuilding the library with a different minimum value.
I would not recommend this for security reasons.